# Good algorithm to calculate max value gained in directed graph, within n steps

Tags: algorithm, graph

The problem is like this:
Each vertex has value Value[i] at i-th step.
(This graph is just a demonstration, not related to later example's calculation)

```
            +----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----  +------+-------+
            |    |     |      |      |     |     |     |    |     |    |      |       |
Value for V1| 2  |  1  |  6   |   4  |    3|   4 |  5  |  1 |   9 | 1  | 10   |   2   |
            |    |     |      |      |     |     |     |    |     |    |      |       |
            +----+-----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+----+------+-------+
```

This step is global step. so when we go from step 1 to step 2, All vertices' value index in its array moves.

The purpose is to find maximum path to gain max values in N steps.

so for example:

we have vertices A,B,C

A value array:  1,4,5,2,3

B value array:  2,1,1,5,4

C value array   3,2,9,6,1

graph: A -> B;  B ->C; C ->A

N: 5  (steps you have)

Optimal path:(start from A always)

A->B->C->C->A

Value: 20

because if we do

A->B->C->C->C value is only 18.

What is the good algorithm to do this?

Dijkstra seems not fit into this.

Comment: Not sure if I follow what you are trying to explain...Given the values in your arrays above and required to start on A, wouldn't the optimal (max result) path for 5 moves be: A, A, C, C, B? If I am correct, then a simple bubble-sort would work fine.

Comment: @gmiley It's a directed graph, A->C doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, so in step 1, A has value 1, in step 2 it has 4, then 5, and similar to B and C. What is with that large table-thing at the top? How is that related to all what? Also, does each node have a reflexive edge, i.e. A->A, B->B, C->C?

Comment: @gmiley that's not going to work because there is no direct path from A to C.

Comment: Ok, so still then, you could use a bubble sort on adjacent array values.

Comment: You can use a basic graph search for this by rewriting your graph: Instead of having nodes A, B, C, you should have nodes A1, ..., A5, B1, ..., B5, C1, ..., C5, and edges from A1 to A2 and B2, etc. Here, node A3 would be the node A at step 3.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, you can image they all have reflexive edges. So if they decide to stay, they can gain the value from that step and move on to next step, on same vertex.

Comment: Dynamic programming should work, too. For each step and for each node, determine the maximum value that that a path leading to that node can have.

Comment: "Each vertex has value Value[i] at i-th step" -- this phrasing means that, at any given time, every vertex has *the same* value.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: There are only 4 steps in your example (unless you count "starting form A" as a step).

Comment: @Nelxiost yes I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an optimal subpath ending at a particular vertex, for every step.

On the first step, find, for every vertex, the subpath ending at this vertex and leading to the maximum value. On the next steps, start with these previous values and repeat. The subpath (and value) is very easy to find, if you store the predecessor of each vertex : just pick the predecessor that has the maximum value.

Example with your input (and reflexive edges) :

```
A values : 1, 4, 5, 2, 3  
B values : 2, 1, 1, 5, 4  
C values : 3, 2, 9, 6, 1  
A successors : A, B
B successors : B, C
C successors : A, C
A predecessors : A, C
B predecessors : A, B
C predecessors : B, C
```

Starting at A and the value 1, the first step leads to :

```
A max : 5 (subpath A->A)
B max : 2 (subpath A->B)
C max : 0 (no subpath)
```

Second step :

```
A max : 10 (subpath A->A->A)    <- the predecessors of A are A and C,
                                   and the previous max value of A
                                   is greater than that of C.
B max : 5 (subpath A->A->B)
C max : 11 (subpath A->B->C)
```

Third step :

```
A max : 13 (subpath A->B->C->A)
B max : 15 (subpath A->A->A->B)
C max : 17 (subpath A->B->C->C)
```

Fourth and final step :

```
A max : 20 (path A->B->C->C->A)
B max : 19 (path A->A->A->B->B)
C max : 18 (path A->B->C->C->C)
```